# Why is it compact?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

[image]
Captured from Chapter11 of Carothers' Real Analysis, 1ed talking about Equicontinuity. How to explain the "Why" there?

Comment: The picture is pretty similar to the proof that $\{0\} \cup \{1/n : n = 1, 2, ...\}$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}$; any sequence in the given set has a subsequence with limit in the set.

Comment: @T.Bongers: If a set A is Cauchy and convergent in metric space X, can I claim that any infinite subsequence of A should be convergent at the same limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with an open cover of $\{f_n : n\geq 1\}\cup \{f\}$, then one open set in that cover contains $f$, and hence contains all but finitely many of the $f_n$'s. Use this fact to find a finite subcover.

Comment: To find such a set of finite subcovers, at least one of these finite subcovers should contain f, is that right?